Using an SPFx Application Customizer in SharePoint 2019 on-prem to display SharePoint List Data
I am struggling to put the final step of this project together successfully. I can create banners and display static information that is able to be deployed successfully, however when I try and add and integrate data from a SharePoint List the whole application blows up and nothing renders. The main issue I can see and understand is I have a promise that I am not able to handle, and the waiting for the responses to be returned for the promise is not functioning. With the lack of meaningful debugging in SPFx I don't know how to progress. Below is an outline of where I am in my thought process and how I am attempting to proceed.
The relevant parts that I am aware of to make this application work are initially creating the interfaces to store the values for the promise function.
export interface SiteColValues {  
  value: SiteColList[];  
}  
export interface SiteColList {  
  URL: string;  
  PagePublisher: string; 
  ContentSteward: string;
}  
function getSiteColListData(): Promise<SiteColValues> {  
  
  return this.context.spHttpClient.get("https://csp.jmrcontoso.com/sites/Default/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SiteInfo')/Items?$filter[URL]="+getCurrentWeb+"&$select=URL,PagePublisher,ContentSteward", SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
  
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {   
        debugger;  
        return response.json();  
      });  
  } 

For the storing of the promise values to usable strings
        let cSteward: String = ""; 
        let pPublisher: String = "";

        getSiteColListData().then(listData => {cSteward.replace} );

For the display of the banner, using html
        let classValue: string = "<div style=\"font-size: 1em; width:600px; float:left;\">Content Steward: " + cSteward + "<br/>Page Publisher: "+ pPublisher +"<br>Last Modified: {0} | Last Reviewed: {1}</div> 

how the banners get added
/** A Custom Action which can be run during execution of a Client Side Application */
export default class HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

    private _top1Placeholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;
    private _top2Placeholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;
    private _bottomPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
  Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

  // Wait for the placeholders to be created (or handle them being changed) and then
  // render.
  this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);

  return Promise.resolve();
}

private _renderPlaceHolders(): void {
  console.log("HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._renderPlaceHolders()");
  console.log(
    "Available placeholders: ",
    this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames
      .map(name => PlaceholderName[name])
      .join(", ")
  );

  // Handling the top1 placeholder
  if (!this._top1Placeholder) {
    this._top1Placeholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
      PlaceholderName.Top,
      { onDispose: this._onDispose }
    );

    // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
    if (!this._top1Placeholder) {
      console.error("The expected placeholder (Top1) was not found.");
      return;
    }

    if (this.properties) {
      let top1String: string = "Test is";
      if (!top1String) {
        top1String = "(Top1 property was not defined.)";
      }

      if (this._top1Placeholder.domElement) {
        this._top1Placeholder.domElement.innerHTML = `
        <div class="${styles.app}">
          <div class="${styles.top1}">
             ${escape(
              top1String
            )}
          </div>
        </div>`;
      }
    }
  }

  // Handling the top2 placeholder
  if (!this._top2Placeholder) {
    this._top2Placeholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
      PlaceholderName.Top,
      { onDispose: this._onDispose }
    );

    // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
    if (!this._top2Placeholder) {
      console.error("The expected placeholder (Top2) was not found.");
      return;
    }

    if (this.properties) {
      let top2String: string = "Test";
      if (!top2String) {
        top2String = "(Top2 property was not defined.)";
      }

      if (this._top2Placeholder.domElement) {
        this._top2Placeholder.domElement.innerHTML = `
        <div class="${styles.app}">
          <div class="${styles.top2}">
             ${escape(
              top2String
            )}
          </div>
        </div>`;
      }
    }
  }
  // Handling the bottom placeholder
  if (!this._bottomPlaceholder) {
    this._bottomPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
      PlaceholderName.Bottom,
      { onDispose: this._onDispose }
    );

    // The extension should not assume that the expected placeholder is available.
    if (!this._bottomPlaceholder) {
      console.error("The expected placeholder (Bottom) was not found.");
      return;
    }

    if (this.properties) {
      let bottomString: string = this.properties.Bottom;
      if (!bottomString) {
        bottomString = "(Bottom property was not defined.)";
      }

      if (this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement) {
        
        let d: Date = new Date();
        let today: String = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        let year = d.getFullYear();
        let month = d.getMonth();
        let day = d.getDate();
        let newdate: String = new Date(year+25,month,day).toISOString().split('T')[0];
        let classValue: string = "<div style=\"font-size: 1em; width:600px; float:left;\">Content Steward: " + cSteward + "<br/>Page Publisher: "+ pPublisher +"<br>Last Modified: {0} | Last Reviewed: {1}</div>;

        this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = classValue;
      }
    }
  }
}

